# java For each object reference stored, call the object methods

Tags: java, list, object, foreach, tostring

I need some help please.
I want to print the phone object and the methods specific to each phone object. I have created a List and for each loop I also have a toString() method which prints the below **Output** what I want to do is call a method streamVideo on a specific phone object Name: G200 using toString().

```
public void streamVideo() {
        System.out.println("Streaming");
}
```

**Output**

```
 Name: LandLine 2000
 No of pixels: 400
 Width: 5.6
 Height: 8.5
 Weight: 80.5
 Powered On: true
 Recharging: false
 Streaming: Streaming at index:0 **// wrong**
```

```
 Name: G200
 No of pixels: 510
 Width: 4.5
 Height: 8.6
 Weight: 80.5
 Powered On: true
 Recharging: false
 Streaming: Streaming at index:1 **// what I want**
```

```
List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    Phone landLine2000 = new Phone("LandLine 2000",400,5.6f,8.5f,80.5f,true,false);
    Phone g200 = new Phone("G200",510,4.5f,8.6f,80.5f,true,false);


    phones.add(landLine2000);
    phones.add(g200);

    int index = 0;
    for (Phone phone : phones) 
    {   
        System.out.println(phone + " at index:" + (index++));
    }

    System.out.println();   

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return ("\n Name: " + getName() +
            "\n No of pixels: " + getNoOfDisplayPixels() + 
            "\n Width: " + getWidth() +
            "\n Height: " + getHeight() +
            "\n Weight: " + getWeight() +
            "\n Powered On: " + getIsPoweredOn() +
            "\n Recharging: " + getIsRecharging() +
            "\n Streaming: " + getStreamVideo() // Don't want to use get
    );
}
```

Comment: `index = 1`? instead of `index = 0`?

Comment: @Ferrybig hmm, not sure what difference your solution will make. I have the index to store the position of the object that I want to use. Well thats what I am trying to do, not sure if it's the right way to select the first object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I want to do is call a method streamVideo on a specific phone
>   object Name: G200 using toString().

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String str = "not Streaming";
    //check whether the name is G200 or not.
    if(getName().equals("G200"))
        str="Streaming";

    return ("\n Name: " + getName() +
            "\n No of pixels: " + getNoOfDisplayPixels() + 
            "\n Width: " + getWidth() +
            "\n Height: " + getHeight() +
            "\n Weight: " + getWeight() +
            "\n Powered On: " + getIsPoweredOn() +
            "\n Recharging: " + getIsRecharging() +
            "\n Streaming: " +str  // Don't want to use get
    );
}
```

Comment: yes that looks good, however I want to call the method streamVideo() but this will not work in toString() as the method is void. I'm wondering do I add the method streamVideo() in the for each loop or extract the object from the for each loop then call the specific object method

Comment: Something like g200.streamVideo();

Comment: @Sayta I used your solution and created this, just wondering is it the right logic
```
int index = 0;
  for (Phone phone : phones) 
  { 
   System.out.println(phone + " at index:" + (index++));
    
     //check whether the name is G200 or not.
     if(phone.getName().equals("G200"))
         phone.streamVideo();
     }